# C# Regex that matches a pattern at the end of an url

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a regex that matches a pattern for urls with the end like **-p123456.html**, so the end it will have a hyphen and the letter *p* followed by a sequence of numbers right before *.html*.

Here are some examples:

- https://www.myurl.com/br/test-url-p04548023.html (MATCH)
- https://www.myurl.com/sometext-p123.html (MATCH)
- https://www.myurl.com/text-h504.html (DOESN'T MATCH)
- https://www.myurl.com/text.html (DOESN'T MATCH)

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: This could work for you if your input will _always_ be a url: `.+\-p\d+\.html$`

Comment: @dvo that works, thanks a lot. If you want to post that as an answer, I can give you an up vote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for your case: `.+\-p\d+\.html$`

Note: You could expand this to do more url validation, but this is quick and easy if you know your input is *always* going to be a url.

**Explanation:**

`.+` - wildcard to start the string. Matches all up until the `-p` you care about

`\-p` - matches literal character `'-'` and `'p'`. Note: you don't have to escape the dash, but I like to because I don't want to confuse it with ranges such as `[a-z]`. You could use `-p` here.

`\d+` - your series of characters (1 or more)

`\.html` - escaping the dot (`'.'`) is important here so it's not just a wildcard. This matches literal `'.html'`

`$` - matches the end of the string so you know the url ends with `-p1234.html`

Comment: Great explanation @dvo! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would say the same here as I did for Nino's (now-deleted) answer: What about the beginning of the URL? This would also match "C:\abcd-p123.html". Is that OK with the OP? In other words, does the OP only want URLs that start with "https://" and have standard URL components before the file at the end?

Comment: yeah, i deleted my answer because @dvo first made a comment that could solve OP's problems, and now it's written as an answer. So, now my answer is unnecessary

Comment: @rory.ap Question does not specify anything about this case. I did leave a note saying there _could be_ more opportunity to validate the url. However based off the wording and sample urls, I'm guessing OP has that part under control

Comment: @dvo I will mark as accepted, I tried before but stackoverflow didn't allow, I have to wait some minutes